# Could not find or load main class net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main fabricmc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft-fabric

I was programming a fabric minecraft mod in intellij and when I ran the code it said :

```
Could not find or load main class net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main
```

When I compiled the code and tried it in minecraft it worked, but in intellij i couldn't run it.

Answer (score 3):

I was messing around with the files, to see if I can fix it and I found a solution :

1. Go to "Run Configuration", press the arrow to see the options and tap "Edit
   Configurations"
   Go to "Minecraft Client" and press the button next to
   "net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main"
   search trough your external libraries and find "net.fabricmc.devlauncherinjector.Main"
   (it must be right under net.fabricmc-api...) select it, and after that you should see
   the "Edit Configurations" window. Press "OK"
2. If this doesn't work, right click the file and select "Copy Full Path". Then go to
   "Edit Configurations" window and paste it where it says
   "net.fabricmc.devlauncherinjector.Main"
3. If the 2 option doesn't work either, close the project, copy the mod folder, and paste
   it somewhere else(eg. Desktop, New Folder). And then open your IDE, go to open project
   and select the copied folder. Press the "Build.gradle" file and select open as project
   and "Trust" .It should now work. If it doesn't , unfortunately I don't know how to fix
   it.

Answer (score 2):

thecoopsyt's answer worked for me.

Go to  Gradle tab > Reload All Gradle Projects

Wait a few mins for it to check and update your dependencies.

After this I was able to return to testing my project in Intellij... had to fully compile and test before this fix.

Answer (score -1):

In Intellij gradle if

this doesn't work you can put

downloadAssets runClient into a gradle config and it will start a client and download the net.fabricmc.devlauncherinjector.Main
this allows you to use gradles built in Minecraft Client